# Rails 3 - source app for Capistrano in directory, not in repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, repository, capistrano

I would like to ask you, if is possible to have as source place for capistrano in directory instead in repository.

I tried

```
set :scm, :none
set :repository,  "."
```

but this gives me an error:
**[err] : File name too long**

It si s possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's possible if the repo located on your server. just use full repo path on server where you do deployment